# XSLT 1 Exclude parent element if not in a list

Tags: xslt

I want to perform an xslt transformation where I split products up by type. As an example:

Source XML:

```
 <Products>
    <Product>
       <Name>Cheese</Name>
       <Value>30</Value>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>Bread</Name>
       <Value>10</Value>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>Bacon</Name>
       <Value>100</Value>
    </Product>
 </Products>
```

Required Output XML:

```
<Products>
    <AnimalProducts>
    <Product>
        <Name>Cheese</Name>
        <Value>30</Value>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <Name>Bacon</Name>
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Product>
    </AnimalProducts>
    <VeganProducts>
    <Product>
        <Name>Bread</Name>
        <Value>10</Value>
    </Product>
    </VeganProducts>
</Products>
```

If there are no animal products, or no vegan products then the parent elements should not be included. I have it half working with:

```
<xsl:variable name="veganProducts" select="'Bread:Lettuce'" />

<xsl:if test="Products/Product[count(*) &gt; 0]">
            <AnimalProducts>
                <xsl:for-each select="Products/Product">
                    <xsl:if test="not(contains(concat(':', $veganProducts, ':'), concat(':', Name, ':')))">     
                        <Product>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                            </Name>
                            <Value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                            </Value>
                        </Product>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </AnimalProducts>

            <VeganProducts>
                <xsl:for-each select="Products/Product">
                    <xsl:if test="contains(concat(':', $veganProducts, ':'), concat(':', Name, ':'))">     
                        <Product>
                            <Name>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Name" />
                            </Name>
                            <Value>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
                            </Value>
                        </Product>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </VeganProducts>
</xsl:if>
```

The problem is I am getting empty parent elements if there are no vegan or animal products in certain cases.  I am unsure how I can test for this.

Comment: Please show a [complete, verifiable sample of the input and XSLT code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good time to make use of variables:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:variable name="veganProductNames" select="'Bread:Lettuce'" />
  <xsl:variable name="veganProductNamesPadded" 
                select="concat(':', $veganProductNames, ':')" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="animalProducts"
                    select="Product[not(contains($veganProductNamesPadded,
                                                 concat(':', Name, ':')))]" />
      <xsl:variable name="veganProducts"
                    select="Product[contains($veganProductNamesPadded,
                                             concat(':', Name, ':'))]" />

      <xsl:if test="$animalProducts">
        <AnimalProducts>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$animalProducts" />
        </AnimalProducts>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:if test="$veganProducts">
        <VeganProducts>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="$veganProducts" />
        </VeganProducts>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<Products>
  <AnimalProducts>
    <Product>
       <Name>Cheese</Name>
       <Value>30</Value>
    </Product>
    <Product>
       <Name>Bacon</Name>
       <Value>100</Value>
    </Product>
  </AnimalProducts>
  <VeganProducts>
    <Product>
       <Name>Bread</Name>
       <Value>10</Value>
    </Product>
  </VeganProducts>
</Products>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to solve this the XML way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<my:vegan-items>
    <item>Bread</item>
    <item>Lettuce</item>
</my:vegan-items>

<xsl:variable name="vegan-items" select="document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:vegan-items/item" />

<xsl:template match="/Products">
    <xsl:variable name="vegan-products" select="Product[Name=$vegan-items]" />
    <xsl:variable name="animal-products" select="Product[not(Name=$vegan-items)]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$animal-products">
            <AnimalProducts>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$animal-products"/>
            </AnimalProducts>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vegan-products">
            <VeganProducts>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$vegan-products"/>
            </VeganProducts>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>                             
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here we are assuming that anything not "vegan" is "animal" (since no list of "animal" items has been provided).

Keeping an external XML document listing the items in each category would probably be even better.

Comment: The real-world definition is more the other way around - anything not "animal" is vegan :-)

Comment: @IanRoberts So a stone would be "vegan"?  -- P.S. What kind of a word is "vegan" anyway? Doesn't it properly indicate an inhabitant of Vega?

Comment: http://www.vegansociety.com/try-vegan/definition-veganism, but this is going way off topic for Stack Overflow now...

Comment: @IanRoberts No, that's vegetarianism. But I guess that's too long a word for that crowd...

Comment: This may be a language difference - in UK English (and probably US too but I'm not qualified to comment on that) "vegetarian" is generally taken to exclude the products of slaughter (meat, gelatine, etc.) but include things obtained from live animals (such as milk and eggs), whereas "vegan" excludes anything animal-derived at all.

Comment: @IanRoberts IMHO those are merely different degrees of vegetarianism.